# ExpressJS: Send Request Header Authentication

Tags: node.js, rest, express, http-headers, http-post

I have an API to authenticate the user with LDAP and I have been provided with the information which includes Content-Type: application/json and username and password for the request header and then the user's username and password to be passed in body. I tried the below code but it's not working. I want to know if I am passing the header request correctly or not.

```
router.post('/user', function(req, res){
      var auth = {
          content-type: "application/json",
          username: "abcd",
          password: "xyze"
      }

      auth.post('/user', {username: req.body.username, password: req.body.password"}, function(response) {
             console.log(response);
      })

})
```

Comment: You are calling `auth.post` while there is no method like that in your object `auth`. What do you want to do?

Comment: So I wanted to authenticate a user based on his username and password along with the header request. Can you tell me how can I do this on express?

Answer (score 0):

Consider use axios package to make your requests: https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios

This link has a section “Creating an instance showing how you can set the header:

```
var instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://some-domain.com/api/',
  timeout: 1000,
  headers: {'X-Custom-Header': 'foobar'}
});
```

Once the header is set, invoke the post method, like this:

```
instance.post('/my/specific/endpoint/', myData);
```

In the following example, you can pass an authentication token as the header to your request:

```
import axios from 'axios';
const MY_BASE_URL = 'https://www.myserver.com/';
class MyLdapService {
  static xhr(accessToken) {
    const options = {
      baseURL: MY_BASE_URL,
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    };
    return axios.create(options);
  }
  static async myPostEndpoint(accessToken, data) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.xhr(accessToken).post('my-endpoint/', data)
        .then(result => resolve(result.data.card))
        .catch(err => reject(this.createError(err)));
    });
  }
}
```

So you can invoke the POST endpoint like this:

```
MyLdapService.myPostEndpoint('my_access_token', {});
```

Comment: The code that you have written is for header authentication. Am I right?

Comment: Then how do I pass the instance to the post request?

Comment: Hey @Monsters, I edited my comment to give you more details on it. Hope it helps!